# A person has 8 friends and plans to invite 5 of them to a party, how many combinations are there if 2 of those friends must attend together?

Tags: combinatorics

A person has 8 friends and plans to invite 5 of them to a party, how many combinations are there if 2 of those friends must attend together?

My first thought was that since two of those friends have already been chosen, then we must only chose a triplet from the remaining 6 friends, or $\binom {6}{3} = 20$ however, my book says that the answer is $26$, I do not understand where the $26$ comes from, and I also don't see where my reasoning is going wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not considering the case in which *both friends don't attend the party*, in that case there will be a total of ${6 \choose 5} $ combinations, so that will give you $26$ combinations in all.

Answer (score 0):

There are $\binom {6}{3} = 20$ possible ways for inviting the two. Also, there are $\binom {6}{5} = 6 $ ways of not inviting them. Thus, there are 26 possible invitations that satisfy these criteria ($\binom {6}{3} + \binom {6}{5} = 26$)